# Unable to integrate TFS in Intelli J 14.1.7 community edition

Tags: intellij-idea, tfs, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

For my existing project they use TFS. As TFS is not integrated in IntelliJ. I tried to follow steps which I saw in a video on how to set up TFS in IntelliJ, but unable to find any repository to add Visual studio TFS. . [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YnZs.png)

Is there a way for me to add TFS. I tried to add as external plugin but still dont find the option to add. Like you see in the screenshot.

Comment: Please see https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/01/end-of-support-for-tfs-2014-and-older/.

Comment: I checked this link, this link has jar files. When I download this I dont have option to import this.

Comment: You can refer to below steps to install the downloaded jar files

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer? Please let me if it helped you to fix this issue

Comment: Hi Thanks for the plugin, I was able to use this for my Intelli J version 14.1.7 but this TFS will not support the TFS repository of my code. It requires TFS having less than 12 version.

Answer (score 0):

As it is announced in [this blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/01/end-of-support-for-tfs-2014-and-older/) that TFS Integration plugin is no longer supported in 2020.1.

To work with TFS 2015 and above, please use the Azure DevOps plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981-azure-devops

To install the downloaded JAR file. Please follow below steps:

1, In IntelliJ, open plugin settings:

- Linux: from the File menu, select Settings... then Plugins
- Mac: from the IntelliJ IDEA menu, select Preferences... then Plugins
- Windows: from the File menu, select Settings... then Plugins

2, Click the Install plugin from disk... button and browse to the JAR file on disk.

3, Click the Install plugin button and restart IntelliJ IDEA.

The plugin can also be installed from IntelliJ by browsing the Plugin Repository.

1,In IntelliJ, open plugin settings:

- Linux: from the File menu, select Settings... then Plugins
- Mac: from the IntelliJ IDEA menu, select Preferences... then Plugins
- Windows: from the File menu, select Settings... then Plugins

2,Click the Browse repositories... button and search for "Azure DevOps".

4, Click the Install plugin button and restart IntelliJ IDEA.

Please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/java/download-intellij-plug-in) for more information.